# Numbers $1,2,3, ...., 2016$ arranged in a circle

Tags: combinatorics

A student wrote numbers $1,2,3, ...., n$ arranged in a circle, then began with erasing number $1$ then he Leaves $2$ then he erased $3$ and leaves $4$ ......
exemple: if $n=10$ :
in the first round he erased $1,3,5,7,9$ , and leaves $2,4,6,8,10$
in the second round he erased $2,6,10$ and leaves $4,8$
in the third round he leaves $4$ because he erased the last number $(10)$ in the second round, then he erased $8$

The last remaining number in the circle is $4$

if $n=2016$ , what is the last remaining number in the circle?

**My progress:**

In the first round all the odd numbers will be erased $ n=1(\mod2) $
In the second round $ n=2(\mod4) $ will be erased, then $ n=4(\mod8) $....
but in the seventh round we have $ n=0(\mod128) $

Comment: This is an instance of the [Josephus problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let it be that $a_{n}$ is the remaining number if we are dealing
with the numbers $1,2,3,4,5\dots,n$.

If $n$ is sufficiently large then after erasing $1$ and leaving
$2$ we have the numbers $3,4\dots,n,2$ ahead of us.

Comparing this with the situation in which we have the numbers $1,2,3,\dots,n-2,n-1$
ahead of us we conclude that $a_{n}=a_{n-1}+2$ if $a_{n-1}<n-1$
and $a_{n}=2$ otherwise.
So next to the evident $a_1=1$ we have the equality: $$a_{n+1}=\begin{cases}
a_{n}+2 & \text{ if }a_{n}<n\\
2 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Looking at sequence $\left(a_{n}\right)$ the following conjecture
arises:

$$a_{n}=2n-2^{\lceil\log_{2}n\rceil}$$

This conjecture can be proved with induction and we conclude: $$a_{2016}=4032-2^{11}=1984$$

Answer (score 1):

It is quite easy to see that if $n$ is a power of two then the last remaining number on the circle is the last one.

Now, if $n$ is not a power of two then let $k$ be an integer such that $2^{k-1}<n<2^k$. Then $2n-2^k>0$. Consider the following sequence of $2^k$ numbers:
$$0,\ 2n-2^k+1,\ 0,\ 2n-2^k+2,\ \ldots,\ 0,\ n-2,\ 0,\ n-1,\ 0,\ n,\ 1,\ 2,\ 3,\ \ldots,\ 2n-2^k-1,\ 2n-2^k$$ 
and cross them out starting from the first zero on the list. As observed earlier, after all moves $2n-2^k$ will remain on the circle.

Note that after $2^k-n$ steps all zeroes will be crossed out and you will be left with numbers $1,2,\ldots,n$ on a circle and in the next steps you will cross out the numbers just like in the problem statement.

It shows that for arbitrary $n$ the remaining number is $2n-2^k$.

For $n=2016$ we have $k=11$ thus the answer is $2\cdot 2016-2^{11} = 1984$.

Comment: Python script gives $1024$. And in general, $2^{\lfloor{\log_2n}\rfloor}$.

Comment: I don't see a flaw in my solution. Could you check your script or point out a mistake in my proof?

Comment: Why don't you run a manual test on a couple of small values of $n$, say, $9$ thru $16$?

Comment: For $n=9$ I got $2$, for $n=10$ I got $4$, and for $n=11$ I got $6$ which agrees with my answer above. Perhaps I (or you) interpreted the problem incorrectly.

Comment: For $n=11$ I get $[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]$, then $[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]$, then $[4, 8]$, then $[8]$.

Comment: It seems you misunderstood the problem. The numbers lie on a circle and you should cross a number then omit next one then cross and so on. So when you cross 11 then you should omit 2 and cross 4.

Comment: Oh, OK then....